# how to install pymysql at python3.5.2 using pip 18.0?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pymysql

pip is installed at following, but when I try to install PyMySQL, I saw the following errors... how to solve?

```
bquan@ubuntu:~/python$ pip -V
pip 18.0 from /home/bquan/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pip (python 3.5)
bquan@ubuntu:~/python$ sudo pip3 install PyMySQL
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/pip3", line 9, in <module>
    from pip import main
ImportError: cannot import name 'main'
```

Comment: What happens when you omit the `sudo` from the pip command (`pip install pymysql`)? Because when you `sudo pip` you are using `/usr/bin/pip3` whereas `pip` (without sudo) seems to be `/home/bquan/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pip` (the one you probably want to use)

Comment: bquan@ubuntu:~/python$ pip3 install PyMySQL
<snip>
Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/cryptography-2.3.dist-info'
Consider using the `--user` option or check the permissions.

Comment: then will show above Permission deny error, pls help!

Comment: not `pip3 install`. Try `pip install`